# Handling duplicate rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a date frame df, let's say with 5 columns : a, b, c, d, e.

```
  a   b   c    d    e

  1   6   x    8    3
  2   3   y    2    3
  3   5   d    1    1
  3   4   g    3    4
  5   3   z    3    1
```

This is what I want to do, for all the rows with same value of column a, I want to drop duplicates, but value of column b should be summed across those rows, and for rest of the columns, I want to keep the first value.

Final Data frame will be :

```
  a   b   c    d    e

  1   6   x    8    3
  2   3   y    2    3
  3   9   d    1    1
  5   3   z    3    1
```

How to do this?

Comment: You can use an the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method to collect rows corresponding to unique values in any given column, and then use the groupby object's `aggregate` method to sum these up. But that might not work well for the column `c` because it contains strings. You might have to handle that separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assign to column 'b' the result of grouping on 'a' and summing, you can then drop the duplicates:

```
In [171]:

df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('sum')
df
Out[171]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  6  x  8  3
1  2  3  y  2  3
2  3  9  d  1  1
3  3  9  g  3  4
4  5  3  z  3  1
In [172]:

df.drop_duplicates('a')
Out[172]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  6  x  8  3
1  2  3  y  2  3
2  3  9  d  1  1
4  5  3  z  3  1
```